# Rails 3 Activerecord TimeWithZone to String without offset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, activerecord

I have:

```
irb(main):016:0> t[0].change_date
=> Tue, 08 May 2012 18:33:53 FET +03:00
irb(main):017:0> t[0].change_date.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
irb(main):018:0> t[0].change_date.to_s
=> "2012-05-08 18:33:53 +0300"
```

How Can I get a string representation of datetime but without offset **+3000**? I need only **"2012-05-08 
18:33:53"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strftime` to format the way you would like to view the `datetime`.
[The strftime documentation.](http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strftime)

So, in your case, if you would like to see the date as: `2012-05-08 18:33:53`, then use:

`t[0].change_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the helper method in ActiveSupport like

```
 t[0].change_date.to_formatted_s(:db)
```

As the to_fomatted_s is aliased to_s  you can also use

```
 t[0].change_date.to_s(:db)
```

You can check support for time formats in the documentation date format (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#DATE_FORMATS)